# Where is the template for the promoted to front page items?

Tags: theming

I want to add some elements and icons into the promoted items template but I can't find where this template is located.

For example, right now my page is rendering:

```
<article id="node-62" class="node node-blog node-promoted node-teaser contextual-links-region clearfix" about="/sites/sample/content/sample" typeof="sioc:Post sioct:BlogPost">
  <h2 property="dc:title" datatype=""><a href="/sites/sample/content/sample">Sample</a></h2>
  <div class="submitted">
    //blah blah blah
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    //blah blah blah
  </div> 
</article>
```

Instead, I would like to add things like:

```
<article id="node-62" class="node node-blog node-promoted node-teaser contextual-links-region clearfix" about="/sites/sample/content/sample" typeof="sioc:Post sioct:BlogPost">
  <i class="icon-menu"></i>
  <div class="something">Maybe some other stuff</div>
  <h2 property="dc:title" datatype=""><a href="/sites/sample/content/sample">Sample</a></h2>
  <div class="submitted">
    //blah blah blah
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    //blah blah blah
  </div> 
</article>
```

Or anything else I want in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This is tipically done in node.tpl.php in your theme. Just keep in mind that this template works for any node, so you should introduce some logic to check if the node is promoted, e.g.

```
<?php if ($node->promoted) { ?>
  <i class="icon-menu"></i>
  <div class="something">Maybe some other stuff</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Yeah I actually ended up doing if teaser and I already had it in my page.tpl anyway. Once I saw it I had it. Thanks, yours looks like something I didn't know.

Answer (score 1):

Nodes promoted to front page uses teaser view by default,so looking for an answer how to theme node teaser view might be your answer.

Below are references for how to theme node teaser view.

- https://drupal.org/node/53464

Or as an option you can have separate template for your node teaser view,in order to make the template recognized by drupal here is some sample code.

```
function mythemename_preprocess_node(&$variables, $hook) {
  if($variables['elements']['#view_mode'] == 'teaser'){
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][]= 'node__teaser';
  }
}
```

and then add `node--teaser.tpl.php` inside your theme/templates,keeping the html the way you want to arrange the elements.

Comment: Yeah I actually ended up doing if teaser and I already had it in my page.tpl anyway. Once I saw it I had it. I'm not great with php so staying out of the template as much as possible is the game for me lol.